# How can I cycle the next item in my list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a wall placement script for a unity project where you place posts down and if the post is close enough to another post a wall will instantiate between them. The problem I'm coming across is cycling the objects in my list to find the 2 objects that determine distance, currentPost and previousPost.

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject wall;
[SerializeField]
private GameObject post;

public GameObject currentPost;
public GameObject previousPost;

private List<GameObject> posts = new List<GameObject>();

private void Update()
{
    GetInput();
    Debug.Log(posts.Count);
    Debug.Log("Distance" + Distance());
}

private void AdjustWalls()
{   

    previousPost = posts[0]; //here is where I'm hoping to make the cycling change
    if(Distance() > 10)
    {
        Debug.Log("wall Placed");
    }
}

private void AddPosts()
{
    currentPost = ((GameObject)Instantiate(post, gridSnap(getWorldPoint()), Quaternion.identity));
    posts.Add(currentPost);
    AdjustWalls();       
}

private void GetInput()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
    {
        AddPosts();
        currentPost.transform.parent = transform;
    }
}

public float Distance()
{
    return Vector3.Distance(currentPost.transform.position, previousPost.transform.position);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you do this in `AddPost` instead by doing the following and removing the `previousPost = posts[0];` line from `AdjustWalls()`?:

```
private void AddPosts()
{
    if(currentPost != null)
    {
       previousPost = currentPost;
    }
    currentPost = ((GameObject)Instantiate(post, gridSnap(getWorldPoint()), Quaternion.identity));
    posts.Add(currentPost);
    AdjustWalls();       
}
```